# MySQL: find rows with number difference

Tags: mysql

I need to find all rows that contain number differences between the `sourceText` and `targetText` fields, e.g.

```
`sourceText`='15.4 g' and `targetText`='15.8 г'

`sourceText`='30 g pack fresh coriander, leaves chopped' and `targetText`='връзка кориандър, нарязана'

`sourceText`='<bpt x="1" i="1" type="bold"/>baby aubergines: <ept i="1"/>4, cut into wedges' and `targetText`='<bpt x="1" i="1" type="bold"/>млади патладжани:<ept i="1"/> 3 бр., нарязани на резени')
```

but not:

```
`sourceText`='<bpt x="1" i="1" type="bold"/>SKILL:<ept i="1"/>' and `targetText`='ТРУДНОСТ:'
```

In PHP, I'd use regex with a negative lookbehind but I can't use negative lookbehinds in MySQL (I found this out yesterday while reading and testing).

So far, I've got to this query:

```
SELECT sourceText, targetText FROM `tmx_data` 
WHERE sourceText REGEXP '([^="])[0-9]+' <> targetText REGEXP '([^="])[0-9]+';
```

to avoid any numbers that are inside the formatting tags. But it is not returning all actual number differences. It only returns the '30 g pack fresh coriander, leaves chopped' row.

I noticed that the query doesn't return all actual number differences even without the negation part:

```
SELECT sourceText, targetText FROM `tmx_test` 
WHERE sourceText REGEXP '[0-9]+' <> targetText REGEXP '[0-9]+';
```

This returns the '30 g pack fresh coriander, leaves chopped' row and the 'SKILL:' row.

I've made this SQL fiddle with samples: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/usnzsqVMf1xVA76euSH6TE/0

I hope someone can help me improve my query.

Comment: [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) returns `1`, `0` or `null`, not the match(es) - [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/usnzsqVMf1xVA76euSH6TE/2). If using MySQL ≥ 8.0.4 you might be able to use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) and it does support lookaround zero-length assertions - [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/usnzsqVMf1xVA76euSH6TE/3).

Comment: @user1191247, thanks! I'm using MySQL 5.7. Your fiddle, like mine, doesn't return accurate results for all rows because it fails for fractions (e.g. 15.4 = 15,8) and for multiple numbers (e.g. "1 14.5 oz. can" = "1 кутийка 400 г")...

Comment: @user1191247, I'm testing the `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` query on MariaDB and it yields the same results as on MySQL 8.x. But I can see it still fails for multiple numbers – it only extracts the first number. Do you know how to solve this problem? (Meanwhile, I've added a comma and a full stop to the regex `'(?<!")[0-9\., ]+'` to capture the decimals and numbers with thousands separators.)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.7 makes this difficult, because it doesn't support the new REGEXP functions and the old REGEXP implementation doesn't support Unicode characters, so it would be hard to filter Cyrillic text anyway.

I implemented a stored function that returns the numeric characters from a string. It's probably grievously slow, but it does return six rows from the sample data you provided.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION numbersOnly(inputText VARCHAR(16383)) RETURNS VARCHAR(16383) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE result VARCHAR(16383) DEFAULT '';
  REPEAT
    IF SUBSTR(inputText, 1, 1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') THEN
      SET result = CONCAT(result, SUBSTR(inputText, 1, 1));
    END IF;
    SET inputText = SUBSTR(inputText, 2);
  UNTIL CHAR_LENGTH(inputText) = 0
  END REPEAT;
  RETURN result;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT sourceText, targetText FROM tmx_data
WHERE numbersOnly(sourceText) <> numbersOnly(targetText);
```

You may want to add some characters to the list in the function, like `.` and `½` and perhaps others.

---

Here's a solution for MySQL 8.0. No stored function required.

```
SELECT * FROM tmx_data
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(sourceText, '[^[:digit:]]', '') <> REGEXP_REPLACE(targetText, '[^[:digit:]]', '');
```

Comment: Thanks! This is beyond what I can understand. I'm no even sure how to wrap this in my PHP code... Do I put all of this inside my `$query = $db->prepare("...");` statement?

Comment: You would only need to create the stored function once, similar to when you create a schema or a table. Then you use the function in query expressions, which I showed on the last lines of my example. If this is beyond what you can understand, perhaps you need to study about creating stored routines in MySQL.

Comment: So, if I switch to mySQL 8.x, there will be an easier solution? I'd be able to use something like this: `(?<!\="|_)[\d+]` – which is what I use in PHP? I can switch to MySQL 8.x on my local server (WAMP) but I'm not sure if my hosting company supports it (it probably does but I'll hae to check).

Comment: Do check, because support for MySQL 5.7 is ending this month (October 2023). I'll add an example that works on MySQL 8.0 in my answer above.

Comment: the MySQL 8.x version works on MariaDB 11.x, too. I'll try adding the negative lookbehind to it because at the moment, it yields some incorrect results: the row where numbers are contained inside the TMX tag (`<bpt x="1" i="1" type="bold"/>SKILL:<ept i="1"/>`). BUT it captures cases where there are two numbers and the second number is different!